# jQuery how to remove the comma before first element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, push

I am getting an array using jQuery push(). But there is a comma before the first element. I need the array without the comma for the first element (but I need a comma for the rest of the elements). Any ideas?

```
function delImg(newThis){
    $(newThis).parent().hide();
    var Id = $(newThis).siblings('.hidden').html();
    Ids.push(Id);
    alert(Ids);
    return Ids;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are adding a empty element to array so you get `,` at starting

```
function delImg(newThis) {
    $(newThis).parent().hide();
    var Id = $(newThis).siblings('.hidden').html();
    if ($.trim(id) !== '') { //push to array if id value is not empty
        Ids.push(Id);
    }
    alert(Ids);
    return Ids;
}
```

---

Comment: you need to .trim() the HTML of Id.

Comment: @writeToBhuwan ty Sir but i'm using `$.trim()` .

Answer (score 0):

```
function delImg(newThis) {
    $(newThis).parent().hide();
    var Id = $(newThis).siblings('.hidden').html().trim();
    if (Id !== '') {
        Ids.push(Id);
    }
    alert(Ids);
    return Ids;
}
```

Comment: But the 0th element is un defined still.